# How to efficiently compute $(\frac{x}{x_i})^{-1} \mod x_i$ where $x = \prod_{i=1}^{n} x_i$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, inverse, chinese-remainder-theorem

How to efficiently compute $(\frac{x}{x_i})^{-1} \mod x_i$ for $i = 1, \ldots, n$?

Suppose $x = \prod_{i=1}^n x_i$ for co-prime integers $x_i$ and $x_j$ ($i \neq j$).

We want to compute $y_i=((\frac{x}{x_i})^{-1} \mod x_i)$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$.

The naive solution to this approach is computing $a_i = \frac{x}{x_i} = \prod_{j\neq i}^n x_j$ first.
Then, apply $a^{-1}\mod x_i$.

Is it possible to compute $y_i$ via $\prod_{j\neq i}(x_j^{-1} \mod x_i)  $??

When each $x_i$ is single-word size (say, within 64-bit). The latter approach allows us not to use multi-precision library :)

Comment: $(ab) ^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1} $

Comment: $x_i=0(mod x_i)$ so there is something wrong here

Comment: @miraunpajaro $a \mod a$ never happens in this case.

Comment: @mallea what I mean is that  $(\frac{x}{x_i})^{-1} \mod x_i$ makes little sense to me. it's like diving by zero isn't it?

Comment: @miraunpajaro It's not division as in division in ring $Z_{x_i} $ just regular division in $Z$, for example $15/3=5$ for example and then take inverse of it. It's not like $15\cdot 3^{-1}$ which wouldn't make sense because $3^{-1}$ doesn't exist.

Comment: @kingW, so, how about $14/3$, what's that in $\mathbb{Z}_3$

Comment: @miraunpajaro The OP said that $x=x_1\cdots x_n$ so $x$ has to be divisible by $x_i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bezout's Theorem gives an efficient method to compute inverse:

Let $a,b$ two numbers with $(a,b)=1$. Then exists $b^{-1}$ over $\mathbb{Z}_a$.

Bezout caims: $$\exists m,n\mbox{ such that } am+bn=1$$

Then if you take $\mod(a)$ you get:

$$bn\equiv 1 \mod(a)$$

Now the question is:

**How to determine such n?**

This comes from Euclidean algorithm:

$r_0=a=bq_0+r_2$

$r_1=b=r_2q_1+r_3$

$r_2=r_3q_1+r_4$
and so on ;)

Comment: Can we do this for each $(x_j^{-1} \mod x_i)$ for j = 1...n?

Comment: It’s really fast if you add the fast multiplication algorithm

Comment: Thank you very much!